# Test data generator for Mongo?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to generate json data (seed data) to be able to test my new application written in Express/MongoDb.
I tried someone online solutions like: http://json-generator.com/ but I was wondering if there's a npm package for that?

Comment: this is known as `db seeding`, package that could help you, https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-seed

Comment: but it doesn't really create random data with a template right? you have to write JS functions to generate them manually?

Comment: please you look at this, https://github.com/tj/node-migrate along with this, https://github.com/marak/Faker.js/.

Comment: I have added it as an answer, please take a look. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This process is known as [Database seeding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_seeding).

> Database seeding is the initial seeding of a database with data. This is often an automated process that is executed upon the initial setup of an application. The data can be dummy data or necessary data such as an initial administrator account.

You can use npm package [Faker](https://github.com/Marak/Faker.js) to generate random data and seed the data in your db.

You can use npm package [node-migrate](https://github.com/tj/node-migrate) to seed with commands.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the benerator community edition, we just added mongo DB support in our new version rapiddweller-benerator-ce 3.0.0.

[check our project on github](https://github.com/rapiddweller/rapiddweller-benerator-ce)